How to Cancel Previous Asynchronous Requests?
Background
I'm working on a UITableView that loads with preloaded data, then fetches additional items asynchronously. When I spam pull-to-refresh, each pull triggers a new async request, resulting in multiple callbacks and duplicate items.
I need to ensure that:
Only the latest create() call's async results are processed.
Previous async requests are ignored or canceled, avoiding duplicate items.

Edit your question and post your real code. There is no async tasks shown in your code. I suggest you take a look at NSCache and make sure your data is not cached before making a new request.

I'm using DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) { }  to illustrate that items are loaded asynchronously with a delay, simulating a network request to keep the post high-level.

You can't cancel DispatchQueue. We need to see real code involving something that can be cancelled.

@matt I understand; perhaps I should have clarified that, from the caller's perspective, we only know that data arrives asynchronously without knowing the specific mechanism providing it. Ideally, the underlying technology should be abstracted away so that it doesn’t affect how we handle cancellations. I hope that makes sense.

Well, from a higher architectural point of view, you need to associate a download-in-progress with something that the table view datasource knows about (like, the underlying datamodel) so that the datasource can cancel the download for any row whose data is for some reason no longer needed (e.g. the row was scrolled out of view before the download finished, or the user refreshes as you suggest). This is a well-plowed field and you can find out all about it by looking at existing posts on Stack Overflow. It isn't clear what you need to know that's new here.

It seems you have two different issues here. One is potentially debouncing or throttling refresh requests. Ie if a refresh is already in progress you should not initiate another one. This is much simpler than trying to cancel an in-progress refresh since with cancellation you potentially need to deal with rolling back partial results. The second issue is one of de-duplication since there may always be the possibility of receiving duplicate items whether the refresh requests overlap or are independent in time.

@Rob Thanks for the insights! I'm aiming for an abstraction layer where providers can supply items asynchronously, without needing to know or enforce how they’re doing it. Each provider is free to handle its own async work however it prefers (some use URLSession, others might use different methods), and we simply treat the results uniformly once provided. I now have my doubts when reading the comments - maybe this is not even possible?

@Paulw11 Thank you for your advice! Indeed, it might make more sense to simply not start a new refresh instead of rolling back partial results. That should be as simple as adding a boolean flag somewhere in the code, I suppose?

You asked:

To handle this, I need a way to cancel any previous pending requests each time pull-to-refresh is triggered, ensuring only the latest request is processed.

And in the comments you clarified:

I’m aiming for an abstraction layer where providers can supply items asynchronously, without needing to know or enforce how they’re doing it.

You provided a completion-handler-based example; an asynchronous API for AsyncProvider that was merely loadItems(completion:). And more to the point, you did not specify any explicit cancellation mechanism for either AsyncProvider in general, or for the specific call to loadItems in particular. In short, you have not specified any mechanism to cancel the request.
If you survey the completion-handler-based asynchronous API, there are a variety of different cancellation patterns, including (but not limited to):

Cancel all requests.
CoreLocation offers a cancelGeocode function, which simply cancels any geocode requests that might be in progress … but there is nothing to identify a particular geocode request.

Let the provider cancel a request.
The Photos framework’s PHImageManager, each request returns its own identifier, and you then supply that identifier to the image manager’s cancelImageRequest.

The provider returns an object that can be cancelled.
In URLSession, functions like dataTask return a URLSessionTask, which you can cancel on that task object, itself.

You create a cancellable object that is supplied to the provider.
CloudKit uses an Operation-based pattern, where you create a CKFetchRecordsOperation, and you can then use the cancel interface offered by Operation.


Bottom line, there is no single consistent pattern for canceling completion-handler-based asynchronous API (though most well-written API offer some sort of cancelation mechanism). Thus, we cannot offer a single pattern for canceling some generic completion-handler-based AsyncProvider. Or, if you did (for example, a protocol modeled after the PHImageManager pattern) you’d have to write some shim for those asynchronous API that adopt different patterns.

In Swift concurrency, however, there is a single, consistent mechanism for canceling asynchronous work. So, let us consider an async-await rendition of your AsyncProvider:
final class AsyncProvider {
    func loadItems() async throws -> [String] {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(5))
        return ["Async Item"]
    }
}

Now the view controller (or what have you) the pattern would be:
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var previousTask: Task<[String], Error>?

    …

    func reloadData() async throws {
        // cancel prior task, if any, here
        previousTask?.cancel()

        // wrap `loadItems` in a `Task`
        let task = Task {
            try await provider.loadItems()
        }

        // save it
        previousTask = task

        // now await it (and handle cancellation, too)        
        try await withTaskCancellationHandler { 
            let items = try await task.value
            // do something with items here
        } onCancel: { 
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}

The difference between the legacy completion-handler-based approaches and this Swift concurrency pattern is that the latter offers a consistent cancellation pattern.
Swift concurrency simplifies this “layer of abstraction”, because every Swift concurrency API should handle cancellation via the same mechanism, namely the cancellation of the task.

You said:

When calling loadItems(), it can potentially create a new instance with the same data each time. However, because each instance is technically unique, simply checking if the item already exists in the items array before adding it won’t work.

I might encourage you to investigate “diffable data sources”. See WWDC 2019 video Advances in UI Data Sources. It greatly simplifies the process and gracefully handles this “I’ve got an updated data model with a mix of unchanged data and updates; refresh the table for me” process.

Besides giving an answer to my question you always gave some valuable insights in trying a different approach, thank you @Rob !
